# How to control text overflow in Flutter when using a Text widget in a dropdown?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I'm using the next piece of code to render an item for a Dropdown component on Flutter web:

```
  Widget _getColorInfo(int color, String text) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Container(
          width: 10,
          height: 10,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Color(color),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(width: 5),
        Text(
            text,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Color(color),
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: ShapeStyle.standardFontSize,
            ),
          ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Now the problem is that if I do not use Flex or Expanded the widget will not recognize the overflow:
[Overflow on the selected item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpK9K.png)
And the dropdown is working:
[Overflow on the expanded panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwguq.png)
Now, if I use Flex the overflow is now recognized by the main component:

```
Flexible(
          child: Text(
            text,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Color(color),
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: ShapeStyle.standardFontSize,
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

[Overlfow handled on the selected item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uNyc.png)

But now the dropdown is not working since it detects the 'size' property is missing:
[Error on the expanded panel of the dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Q7TL.png)
Here is the error:
[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0MTn.png)

The problem is that I can't use the size of the screen to determine how much width is the component taking since all the other components are being expanded dynamically, so it will break the UI symmetry. Is there any other way to control the overflow when using a dropdown or something to differentiate the dropdown panel from the selected item so I can apply different strategies like using a fixed width for the dropdown panel and a Flex for the selected item?

I have already tried using Flex, Expanded, try catch, Wrap, ConstrainedBox, third party packages... nothing solved the problem.

**UPDATE**

Here is the full code of the component:

```
class ColorSelect extends StatelessWidget {
  final AgendaFormHandler form;
  final int? defaultColor;
  final Map<String, int> elements = {
    'Team 1': 0xFFFEC000,
    'Team 2': 0xFF65CBFD,
    'Team 3': 0xFFF2B085,
    'Team 4': 0xFF01AE51,
    'USO': 0xFF3764F7,
    'Financiero': 0xFF702FA0,
    'Procesos': 0xFF8FA9DA,
    'TI': 0xFFFF7C81,
    'Alterno 1': 0xFF00F3EB,
    'Alterno 2': 0xFFA46B6B,
    'Alterno 3': 0xFFDCBFB2,
    'Alterno 4': 0xFFEF5CEF,
    'Alterno 5': 0xFFC5D89F,
  };

  ColorSelect({super.key, required this.form, this.defaultColor});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SimpleSelectInput<int>(
      title: 'Color',
      customEmptyText: 'Ninguno',
      activeOption: form.getValue<int?>('color') ?? defaultColor ?? 0xFFFEC000,
      onOptionSelected: (color) {
        form.updateValue('color', color);
      },
      options: List<SelectItem<int>>.from(elements.keys.map((key) {
        return SelectItem(
          value: elements[key]!,
          text: key,
          label: _getColorInfo(elements[key]!, key),
        );
      })),
    );
  }

  Widget _getColorInfo(int color, String text) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Container(
          width: 10,
          height: 10,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Color(color),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(width: 5),
        Flexible(
          fit: FlexFit.tight,
          child: Text(
            text,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Color(color),
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: ShapeStyle.standardFontSize,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the code of the SimpleSelectInput

```
/// A class to create a new option entry for the [SimpleSelectInput]
/// component with [T] as the datatype for the [value] and [String]
/// for the [label]
class SelectItem<T> {
  final T value;

  /// This text is only to be able to compare the content of the
  /// input when applying any search filter. So, the same you put
  /// in the [label] property is the one you should put here.
  final String text;
  final Widget? label;

  SelectItem({
    required this.value,
    this.label,
    required this.text,
  });
}

/// A simple input with a bottom border and a blue title with
/// [T] as the value datatype for the dropdown options.
class SimpleSelectInput<T> extends StatelessWidget {
  /// The options to be displayed in the dropdown
  final List<SelectItem<T>> options;

  /// The item to be rendered as the default selected item
  final T activeOption;
  final Function(T?) onOptionSelected;
  final String Function(T?)? validator;
  final String? title;
  /// The text to be displayed when no option is selected
  final String? customEmptyText;
  final bool shouldDecorate;
  final bool showSearchBox;

  const SimpleSelectInput({
    super.key,
    required this.options,
    required this.activeOption,
    required this.onOptionSelected,
    this.title,
    this.validator,
    this.shouldDecorate = true,
    this.showSearchBox = false,
    this.customEmptyText = '-- Seleccione --',
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (activeOption == null) {
        return Container();
    }

    // If there is no opportunity it will raise an error.
    // TODO: check if it's ok to raise the BadState error.
    late final SelectItem<T>? selectedOption;

    try {
      selectedOption = options.firstWhere(
        (SelectItem<T> option) {
          return option.value == activeOption;
        },
      );
    } catch (_) {
      selectedOption = null;
    }

    return DropdownSearch<SelectItem<T>>(
      items: options,
      selectedItem: selectedOption,
      filterFn: (item, filter) {
        return item.text.toLowerCase().contains(filter.toLowerCase());
      },
      dropdownButtonProps: const DropdownButtonProps(
        focusColor: ColorStyle.blue,
        color: Colors.black,
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.arrow_drop_down,
          size: ShapeStyle.standardFontSize * 1.4,
        ),
      ),
      dropdownBuilder: (context, value) {
        return value?.label ??
            Text(
              customEmptyText ?? '-- Seleccione --',
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: ShapeStyle.standardFontSize,
              ),
            );
      },
      validator: (selected) {
        return validator?.call(selected?.value);
      },
      popupProps: PopupPropsMultiSelection.menu(
        showSearchBox: showSearchBox,
        showSelectedItems: true,
        itemBuilder: _itemBuilder,
        searchFieldProps: const TextFieldProps(
          scrollPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: ColorStyle.blue,
            fontSize: ShapeStyle.standardFontSize,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      compareFn: (i, s) => i.value == s.value,
      dropdownDecoratorProps: DropDownDecoratorProps(
        dropdownSearchDecoration: InputDecoration(
          fillColor: Colors.black,
          border: shouldDecorate ? null : InputBorder.none,
          labelStyle: const TextStyle(
            color: ColorStyle.blue,
            fontSize: ShapeStyle.standardFontSize * 1.4,
          ),
          label: title != null
              ? Text(
                  title!,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: ShapeStyle.standardFontSize * 1.4,
                  ),
                )
              : null,
        ),
      ),
      onChanged: (x) => onOptionSelected(x?.value),
    );
  }

  Widget _itemBuilder(
      BuildContext context, SelectItem<T> item, bool isSelected) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Container(
      width: size.width,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        vertical: 12.0,
        horizontal: 8.0,
      ),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          item.label ??
              Text(
                item.text,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: ShapeStyle.standardFontSize,
                ),
              ),
          // a check icon
          if (isSelected)
            const Icon(
              Icons.check,
              color: Colors.green,
              size: ShapeStyle.standardIconSize,
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: does using `fit: FlexFit.tight` help? have a try

Comment: Hi @Delwinn, I just tried that, still the same behavior, it raises an error when I expand the dropdown.

Comment: can you update the question with dropdown widget code too?

Comment: @Delwinn I just updated the post